# Changing the Format of XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xslt

I have the following Xml :

```
<Root>
  <Username>
    <string>Fred</string>
    <string>John</string>
  </Username>
</Root>
```

What I need is a Xml formatted like this:

```
 <Root>
    <Username>Fred</Username>
    <Username>John</Username>
 </Root>
```

Is there a way to achieved that?

Comment: You want to create malformed xml?

Comment: Of course, yes, you can do that...

Comment: Your second XML has </string>. My guess is you don't want that in there.

Comment: Sorry, I update, wrong copy paste...

Comment: I need to do in in c#, I receive a file in the first format but my code only handle the code in the second format...

Comment: Do you need to do this programmatically or is this a one-off?

Comment: Can you use Schema and XmlDocument ?

Comment: How can I use Schema and XmlDocument to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq-to-XML:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

var indoc = XDocument.Load("c:\\test.xml");   
var outdoc = new XDocument(
              new XElement("Root", 
                indoc.Descendants("Root")
                     .Descendants("Username")
                     .Elements()
                     .Select(n => n.Value)
                     .Select(i => new XElement("Username", i))));

// TODO: Save doc using doc.WriteTo(xmlWriter) to the file
```

Answer (score 1):

Set this above your property:

[XmlArray("Username")]

Comment: I suspected he was using serialization because with serialisation you get those <string> blocks. With any other method (at least I know) he should have been able to choose the name he wanted in it.

Comment: He says he receives a file, so I don't think so.